# Git: Accidentally merged conlfict notes into branch. How do I remove them?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I accidentally merged conflict notes (`<<<<<<< HEAD`) into a development branch.

I didn't think that was such an issue, as I thought I could just tidy them up on my local and merge them again. But that didn't work - though my branch is clean, the development branch still has the erroneous code.

I then thought I could `checkout` (`git checkout master <file>`) a copy of the file from the production branch, redo my changes and push it up again. Again, that didn't work and the development branch still has the problem.

Then, I tried to `checkout` (`git checkout development-branch <file>`) the same file from the broken development branch thinking I could see the bad code and delete it there. Again no luck.

Looking at my branch on Github, I can see it is clean.

Would anyone know what I could do?

Comment: If you have merged something into `development`, than checking out `development` will show it in the merged state. This includes the `<<<< HEAD` line that you erroneously merged. You are saying that the `development` branch has a line you wish to remove and you also say that 'my branch' is clean. What is 'my branch'?

Comment: @Matt, I'm pretty new to git so havent got the terminology down.

At my work there are 3 versions of the site - 1 on my local, 1 on a development server and 1 on a production server. I created a new branch `css-updates` to make some changes, then merged those changes with the development server (along with the <<<< HEAD I should have deleted).

Comment: That's fine, I'll try to explain more in an answer.

Comment: @Matt, sorry accidenatlly hit enter before I finished typing. More details above.

Comment: Are you actually merging anything (i.e. `git merge` a feature branch into the master branch), or are you pushing your local master branch to the remote development master branch (i.e. `git push`)?

Comment: @Matt I'm merging my branch into the development branch (git merge)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing a `git checkout development` on local repo. Then try `git rebase {the branch you cleaned up}`. See if that resolves the issue on local repo. If it does you can push from the development branch to the remote development branch.